# How to loop over custom fields in a page template?

Tags: php, custom-field, loop, templates

I was originally using a single field and things worked perfectly with the following code. Now I need to alter it to loop of several fields that are similar.

To start: I've created several custom fields on my page (slide1, slide2, slide3) and these fields contain a URL for an image location. Next I created some text fields (slide1_text, slide2_text, etc).

Code wise, I was pulling my fields in my template like:

```
<?php
    // check for slide
    $slide = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'slide1', $single = true);
    // check for slide text
    $thumb_text = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'slide1_label', $single = true);
    // if there's a slide
    if($slide !== '') { ?>
    <section class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="<?php echo $slide; ?>" class="slider-images" />
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h2><?php if($slide_text !== '') { echo $slide_text; } else { echo the_title(); } ?></h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <?php } // end if statement
?>
```

Basically it checks to see if there is a field called slide1 and if so it prints it. I don't know a lot about adding in loops and the end goal here is to return the fields formatted for a bootstrap carousel. (I know there are plugins but I've tried a couple and they aren't exactly what I want.)

How can I alter this code to include a loop so that it will check and see if there are fields titled slide* and if so, loop over them and get them all?

Additionally, it would be great if there were a way I could ensure the first slide had a class of "active" as you can see in the code below `<div class="item active">` and all other fields will only be class=item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to loop through up to 4 slides - checking each for a valid slide:

```
<?php
    $max_slides = 4; // this should be the maximum number of slides there can be

    for ($i=1; $i<=$max_slides; $i++) { 
        // check for slide
        $key = 'slide' . $i; 
        $slide = get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, $single = true);
        // check for slide text
        $thumb_text = get_post_meta($post->ID, $key . '_label', $single = true);
        // if there's a slide
        if($slide !== '') { ?>
            <section class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <img src="<?php echo $slide; ?>" class="slider-images" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h2><?php if($slide_text !== '') { echo $slide_text; } else { echo the_title(); } ?></h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        <?php } // end if statement
    } 
?>
```

You can change `$max_slides` to go through more than 4

Comment: This returns `<img src="Array" />`. I'm checking now to see if I can find out where it's causing that. Also, when I set the max slides to 10 it's printing more slides than are actually on the page's custom fields.

Comment: I think I had a bug - just edited my answer to fix - specifically this line: `$slide = get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, $single = true);` Sorry, need more coffee!

Comment: Excellent. I see what you changed. Thanks. This appears to be working. I will tweak this a bit to get it where I want and try to get the first slide only with the active class. Thanks for your help. As soon as the timer is out I'll accept your answer.